Spaces whose Points violate Homotopy Extension Property
I'm looking for a pair $(X,x)$ consisting of a topological space $X$ with a distinguised point $x \in X$ such that canon inclusion $i_x: x \to X$ is not a cofibration, ie not satisfied homotopy extension property.
There are known several examples for pairs of spaces $(X,A)$ (see eg here or here) violating HEP,
but I would like to see one where $A$ is really just a single point.
Are there also a "heuristic/intuitive" reasons what potentially obstucts/prevents a homotopy $H_A:\{x\} \times I \to T$ with prescribed map $f: X \to T$ to admit such an extension $H_X: X \times I \to T$ with $H_X \vert _{A \times I}=H_A$ and $H_0=f$? ($T$ some test space)
Which picture one should keep in mind seeking for a counterexample? Clearly $(X,x)$ isn't allowed to be a CW-pair, so it becomes rather "weird".
Inspired by this I would guess (but was till now without success in proving it) that
$X = \{0\}\cup\left\{\frac{1}{n} \ : \ n \in\mathbb{N}\right\}$ with $A= x=\{0\}$ (with subspace topology inherited from $\Bbb R$) could have desired properties.
Then a homotopy $H_A:\{x\} \times I \to T$ corresponds simply to a path $p_x: I \to T$. So the question is to find a weird enough "test space" $T$ and a map $f: X \to T$ to it "entangling" bad enough such that potential homotopy $H_X: X \times I \to T$ cannot garantee to restrict to $H_A$ and $f$ simultaneosly.
Is it possible to produce with such $X$ the desired counter example?

Have you considered taking the first example that you posted (where $X=[0,1]$ and $A$ is the terms of the harmonic series union their limit $0$) and passing to the quotient pair $(X/A, )$ (where the point $$ is the image of $A$ under the quotient map)? I don't know for a fact that this will work, but it would be my first guess given that example.

You can at least use your $X$ to build a counterexample. See Example 8.31 in these notes.

There is always universal `test space' to test the HEP. It's the first place to look, and in this case probably the most accessible. Namely, an inclusion $A\subseteq X$ has the HEP if and only if $X\times0\cup A\times I$ is a retract of $X\times I$. It's easy to show that this fails for the pair $(X,{0})$ which you consider.

@Tyrone: presumably I see. I terms of HEP one considers $T:=X\times0\cup A\times I$ with $f: X \to T, H_A: A \times I \to T$ canonical inclusions. Then the hypothetical extension $H_X: X \times I \to T$ would be discontinous with resp sequence $(1/n,1)_n \to (0,1)$. That's the key problem, right?

You should write an official answer to your own question.

@PaulFrost: Ok, but intended not to attribute Tyrone's merit to oneself

@user267839 In your answer you correctly attributed the idea to Tyrone. Your merit is that you cleared the question from the unanswered queue.

following Paul Frost's advice let me just repeat Tyrone's idea (...at least how I understood him) to complete this issue:
We consider as "test space" $T:=X\times0\cup A\times I$ with $f: X \to T, H_A: A \times I \to T$ canonical embeddings. The problem is that any hypothetical extension $H_X: X \times I \to T$ cannot be continuous in $(0,1)$: Consider the sequence $(1/n,1)_n \to (0,1)$ and another sequence $(a_n, 1)_n \to (0,1)$ where $a_n \to 0$ are disjoint from the $1/n$'s, eg all irrational. Then by construction, both converge to $(0,1)$, but $(H_X(a_n, 1))_n$ not converge to $(0,1)$ in contrast to   $ ((H_X(1/n,1))_n=(1/n,1)_n$ as it should for continuous map
